# VHDL function behaves differently in elaborate than in simulation

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, vivado

In a VHDL testbench, I have a function that parses a csv file in order to initialize a test array.

When running the function in the elaboration phase to set the values of a constant, the function behaves differently than when using the same function in simulation (e.g. initializing a signal during a reset)

The function code is:

```
constant    cn_DATA_WIDTH               : natural       := 10;
constant    cn_DATA_DEPTH               : natural       := 400;

type        tav_data_array              is array (0 to cn_DATA_DEPTH - 1)   of std_logic_vector(cn_DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);

function f_init_data_from_file (
    s_file_path     : in string;
    i_column_index  : in integer := 0
) return tav_data_array is
    -- file parsing
    file        f_data_file_buf     : text is in s_file_path;
    variable    vl_data_file_line   : line;
    variable    vi_data_entry       : integer;
    variable    vc_comma            : character;
    variable    vb_good_num         : boolean;
    -- destination
    variable    vav_data_array      : tav_data_array;
begin

    -- Skip first line that contains header
    readline (f_data_file_buf, vl_data_file_line);

    for line_index in vav_data_array'range loop
        
        readline (f_data_file_buf, vl_data_file_line);
        read (vl_data_file_line, vi_data_entry, vb_good_num);

        assert  vb_good_num
            report  "Failed reading file : " & s_file_path
                    & ", at line = "    & integer'image(line_index)
                    & ", at column = 0"
            severity failure;

        for column_index in 1 to i_column_index loop
            read(vl_data_file_line, vc_comma);
            read(vl_data_file_line, vi_data_entry, vb_good_num);

            assert  vb_good_num
                report  "Failed reading file : " & s_file_path
                        & ", at line = "    & integer'image(line_index)
                        & ", at column = "  & integer'image(column_index)
                severity failure;
        end loop;
        
        vav_data_array(line_index) := std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(vi_data_entry, cn_DATA_WIDTH));

    end loop;

    return vav_data_array;

end function;
```

Function usage in elaboration:

```
constant cav_data                : tav_data_array :=
    f_init_data_from_file (
        s_file_path    => "my_path"      ,
        i_column_index => 3
    );
```

Result: The test array is not initialized with the expected data. The data used for the initialization is column 0 instead of column 3.

Function usage in elaboration:

```
signal sav_data                : tav_data_array;

-- ...

process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if rst = '1' then
            sav_data  <= 
                f_init_data_from_file (
                    s_file_path    => "my_path"      ,
                    i_column_index => 3
                );
        else
            -- ...
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

In this case, the data used for initialization is the proper one. Column 3 is used as expected.

Is there a reason for this different behavior? Or is this a bug with the tools I am using for simulation (Xilinx Vivado 2018.2)?

**EDIT to create MRVE:**

As requested, this is a minimal reproducible example. Some of the parameters

Source code:

```
-- MRVE
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

-- File parsing

use STD.textio.all;
use ieee.std_logic_textio.all;

entity file_bug_mrve is
end file_bug_mrve;

architecture a_file_bug_mrve of file_bug_mrve is

    -- Actual data are 12 bits
    constant    cn_DATA_WIDTH               : natural       := 12;
    constant    cn_DATA_DEPTH               : natural       := 4; -- testbench is planned for 400 high priority cycles

    type        tav_data_array              is array (0 to cn_DATA_DEPTH - 1) of std_logic_vector(cn_DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);


    -- Parse csv data file to retrieve all entries at specified columns
    function f_init_data_from_file (
        s_file_path     : in string;
        i_column_index  : in integer := 0
    ) return tav_data_array is
        -- file parsing
        file        f_data_file_buf     : text is in s_file_path;
        variable    vl_data_file_line   : line;
        variable    vi_data_entry       : integer;
        variable    vc_comma            : character;
        variable    vb_good_num         : boolean;
        -- destination
        variable    vav_data_array      : tav_data_array;
    begin

        -- Skip first line
        readline (f_data_file_buf, vl_data_file_line);

        for line_index in vav_data_array'range loop
            readline (f_data_file_buf, vl_data_file_line);
            read (vl_data_file_line, vi_data_entry, vb_good_num);
            assert  vb_good_num
                report  "Failed reading file : " & s_file_path
                        & ", at line = "    & integer'image(line_index)
                        & ", at column = 0"
                severity failure;

            for column_index in 1 to i_column_index loop
                read(vl_data_file_line, vc_comma);
                read(vl_data_file_line, vi_data_entry, vb_good_num);
                assert  vb_good_num
                    report  "Failed reading file : " & s_file_path
                            & ", at line = "    & integer'image(line_index)
                            & ", at column = "  & integer'image(column_index)
                    severity failure;

            end loop;

            vav_data_array(line_index) := std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(vi_data_entry, cn_DATA_WIDTH));

        end loop;

        return vav_data_array;

    end function;    
    
    constant    cs_RSP_DATA_IN_FILE_PATH        : string        := "../../src/xls/file_bug_mrve.csv";
    constant    cn_RSP_DATA_IN_COLUMN_INDEX     : natural       := 3;

    -- registers emulation
    -- Setting init data to be processed in elaboration does not work
    -- Data will be initialized with first column instead of third
    signal      sav_data                : tav_data_array :=
        f_init_data_from_file (
            s_file_path    => cs_RSP_DATA_IN_FILE_PATH      ,
            i_column_index => cn_RSP_DATA_IN_COLUMN_INDEX
        );

    -- infa Simulation
    constant    ct_CLOCK_PERIOD_100             : time :=  10 ns;
    constant    ct_TEST_COMPLETION_TIME         : time :=  ct_CLOCK_PERIOD_100 * 10;
    
    signal      s_clk                           : std_logic;
    signal      s_rst                           : std_logic;
    signal      sb_end                          : boolean           := false;

begin

    
    -- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Clock process definitions
    -- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    p_Clock_100 : process
    begin
        s_clk <= '0';
        wait for ct_CLOCK_PERIOD_100/2;
        s_clk <= '1';
        wait for ct_CLOCK_PERIOD_100/2;
        if sb_end then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
    
    -- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Main Stimulus process
    -- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    p_stimulous : process
    begin
        --
        s_rst       <= '0';
        
        -- 1 clock cycle reset to avoid loading file multiple times
        wait until rising_edge(s_clk);
        s_rst       <= '1';
        wait until rising_edge(s_clk);
        s_rst       <= '0';
        
        wait for ct_TEST_COMPLETION_TIME;
        sb_end      <= true;
       
    end process;

    p_main : process(s_clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(s_clk) then
            if s_rst = '1' then
                
                -- Setting init data to be processed in simulation works
                -- Data will be initialized with forth column as expected
                sav_data            <=
                    f_init_data_from_file (
                        s_file_path    => cs_RSP_DATA_IN_FILE_PATH      ,
                        i_column_index => cn_RSP_DATA_IN_COLUMN_INDEX
                    );

            else
                -- Nothing to do in MRVE
            end if;
        end if;
    end process p_main;
    
end a_file_bug_mrve;
```

CSV file:

```
Ch0,Ch1,Ch2,Ch3
1,5,9,13
2,6,10,14
3,7,11,15
4,8,12,16
```

Comment: Have you tried with a newer version of Vivado? Without a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), difficult to say alot more. Assuming the file is definitely the same, and definitely being read from the same path (Vivado is a bit weird with pathing) then I can only assume tool bug. 2018.2 is 2 years old now. The latest is 2020.1 (with 2020.2 likely to drop soon)

Comment: Creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example for your question your readers using other tools might find that the function should be impure (added in -1993, the file declaration uses -1987 syntax) and that the problem can't be replicated with newer revision VHDL tools (there's an implicit FILE_CLOSE for files declared in subprograms). Try using revision -1993 or newer tool compliance with a compliant file declaration or use two distinct copies of my_path. The semantics of file operations are incompletely defined in -1987. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Tricky I created a full MCVE. I currently only have a 2018.2 Vivado installed, therefore I could not test it with another version. The file is found in elaboration and in simulation, so I don't think the issue is a path issue. As I have a workaround, the answer is not critical for my but I wanted to verify it there was something obvious that I had missed and also benefit the community if there is a solution.

Comment: @ user1155120 I created a full MCVE. I had some compiler warnings about the function not being impure related to the file buffers. However, making the function impure didn't have any impact on the bug. The file was being used at a single place until I added the workaround to parse the file in simulation. Vivado 2018.2 has VHDL-2008 support enabled by default. I didn't try with tools limited to -1993 or -1987.

Comment: While 2018.2 has VHDL2008 support, unless the file is specified as such, it will default to VHDL 1993. I highly recommend a different tool version to see if the issue still exists.

Comment: Decorating the function with **impure**, adding a process sensitive to `sav_data` with a report statement`, modifying the path to the `.csv` file and running your MCVE with ghdl (-1993) gives `ghdl -r file_bug_mrve
file_bug_mrve.vhdl:155:13:@0ms:(report note):
 sav_data = 13, 14, 15, 16`. This indicates the synchronous reset (load) produced no  signal event - `sav_data` was unchanged. Note your MCVE is incomplete, what did you expect and what did running it produce?

Comment: I produced a MCVE [from you original question](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n0t574f2lri7zho/no_mcve.vhdl?dl=1) with the constant declaration and signal assignment having different values with out exhibiting the problem. Your difficulty is undoubtedly a particular version of ISIM or Vivado Simulator not handling initialization using file I/O correctly. Trying the latest would tell you whether or not the bug has been eventually fixed